# Finding the shortest path in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, shortest-path

How to build a NetLogo agent who must try to find the shortest route between all of the given locations whilst also avoiding the given patches as those represent solid impassable objects.

Comment: as a general approach, you could set up links that represent legal moves between one patch and the next, and then use the network shortest path algorithm in the `nw` (network) extension

Answer (score 0):

If you google "shortest route algorithm" you'll find many, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

But you have massively under-specified the problem you are trying to solve.  You want a single agent to solve this? Why not a swarm or class of agents? If just one agent why are you using NetLogo as a tool?  Are the agents smart? Do they get smarter over time? Can 3 agents work together on exploring the terrain?  Does this have to get solved just once or many times?

How much information is available to the agent? The whole world?  Just the nearest radius R?  Does the agent know in advance what the "given locations" are and what the obstacles are?   Does the order in which the given-locations are visited matter?

This could be the classic "**travelling salesman**" problem,  having to visit each of N cities with costs of travel  between each pair being given.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Can the agent find ANY route, and then keep trying to improve it?  Or must it work on the first pass? What's the stopping condition?  How do you know when the best route you've found is the best possible route?

You should also look at the A* algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

There's a huge amount of prior work done on solving this class of problem but they're mostly computational -- ie, your agent could simply sit and plug numbers into software and compute an answer and never move.   I don't think that's what you had in mind.  But what DID you have in mind?